# Does JOGL support NURBS?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, nurbs

I have made some researches on `nurbs` in `jogl`, but unfortunately did not get appropriate result for it, and I have doubt that `jogl` does not support nurbs? If `jogl` supports, can anyone guide me to examples or literature please?

Comment: Does OpenGL support NURBS?

Comment: @immibis GLU supports NURBS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some information about GLU (which contains the Nurbs features) and JOGL [here](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/#joglapi) in the paragraph entitled "GLU". By default, JOGL uses its own Java GLU implementation but you can use the native GLU implementation by using the system property -Djogl.glu.nojava. The former is available on much more platforms and more stable but its NURBS support isn't 100% complete whereas the latter is absent of some platforms and buggy on some others but it provides a better NURBS support.

You can find some working examples [here](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl-demos/tree/master/src/demos/nurbs). Please use [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org) to ask JOGL specific questions as only a few maintainers are on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know JOGL supports Bézier curves. Thus, you could subdivide your NURBS curve into a sequence of Bézier curves and render each Bézier curve one another afterwards. If you are not sure about the subdividing algorithm, have a look at [tinyspline](https://github.com/retuxx/tinyspline) (and the binding for Java).